# Java : JFormattedTextField change setGroupingUsed() on focusLost & focusGained

Tags: java, swing, formatting, caret, jformattedtextfield

I have many JFormattedTextdields with number data in it. I have used DecimalFormat, InternationalFormatter, DocumentListener and also tried with CaretPositionListener.

The only problem I face is caret position when number input grows and grouping character comes in between.

How can I dynamically set setGroupingUsed() of DecimalFormat of respective jformattedtextfields on focusGained & onFocusLost.

Any ideas or suggestions....

**UPDATE CODE & PROBLEM :** 
When I try to input "12345", on adding "1234" a comma appears "1,234". This brings to caret between 3 & 4 instead of after 4. The Formatting code I use :

```
    DecimalFormat numberFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance();
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    final InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(numberFormat);
    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    formatter.setMinimum(0.00);
    formatter.setMaximum(999999999.99);

    return formatter;
```

This is what I have implemented as **SOLUTION** on a custom JFormattedTextField. Do you have any better approach to handle the grouping character while inputting value, so just caret position remains proper :

```
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    if (numberFormat.isGroupingUsed()) {
        Object o = this.getValue();
        numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
        formatter.setFormat(numberFormat);
        this.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactoryImpl());
        this.setValue(o);
        this.setText(o.toString());
    }
}

public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    try {
        this.commitEdit();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(NumberFormattedTextField.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Object o = this.getValue();
    //System.out.println("focusLost : getValue = " + o);
    numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
    formatter.setFormat(numberFormat);
    this.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactoryImpl());
    this.setValue(o);
    this.setText(o.toString());
    //System.out.println("focusLost : Text Set = " + o.toString());
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,

I solved by creating a custom textfield that manages everything I need. Any suggestion for improvements. Code is added above in question.

Comment: each better AutoCompleted JComboBox/JtexField have got implemented set & moveCaret, then there nothing about JTextField, but about extract JTextComponent from JComboBox

Comment: @mKorbel, the problem was while inputting the text. Due to grouping the "," appeared so the caret was 1 digit inner. I set the grouping to false while focusGained and restored to true while focusLost. This helped me. Is their any better solution than mine as to what you are mentioning.

Comment: check for AutoCompleted JComboBox/JtexField, you can put 50pcs and each remembers last Carret with Selection, but in other hands is too hard to answer to your question, because you talking about hight level workaound without code, sure here are a few excelent Swing Coders, but no code, no answer :-)

Comment: @mKorbel, initially I had added all details - the problem I face and the code. But Andrew and other users also mentioned about SSCCE. I edited 2-3 times, but yet couldn't find any reply.

Comment: :-) these Swing Gurus knows 10-15, maybe 100 variations what'll happening when & when & when .... :-) then why do you suprised,